# he "string" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer. Received type object

Tags: javascript, request, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying to send this request through the 2captcha API, but the issue is everytime I send it VIA code it gives me the error:
[ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer. Received type object

Any help would be greatly apricated, I keep trying diffrent things but can't seem to get this request to send.

```html
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

const data = new FormData();
data.append("key", "96000001977a12e50ca4eb45f104fe1");
data.append("file", "file");
data.append("submit", "00000W0UAAAAAA-ouoKHOnWuQDNymSwDFYeGP300");

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true; 

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://2captcha.com/in.php?key=962800000a12e50ca4eb45f104fe1&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey=000000UAAAAAA-ouoKHOnWuQDNymSwDFYeG00000&pageurl=https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo");
xhr.send(data); //problem area
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the particular XMLHttpRequest library you're using does not support the FormData object. See [this bug report](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/issues/174). In general, it looks like this library hasn't been updated in a while. If it's not too difficult (I don't know how deeply rooted this old library is within your project) but I would recommend switching to a more modern solution, like node-fetch, which uses the newer, easier to use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). This [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) package would provide that support for node.

One solution to fix your current problem is to use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) which will let you encode data in the same format that you need, shares a similar API to FormData, but also has a toString function. Your error message says that this library supports strings, so you can just pass in a stringified value.

```js
const data = new URLSearchParams();
data.append("key", "xxx");
data.append("file", "file");
data.append("submit", "yyy");
console.log(data.toString())
```